# get an access_token from an authorized code granted by a user from another Microsoft account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, token

I'm trying to get access to MS Graph API from my application to users of another Microsoft account to avoid to request to our customers they have to create the application themself

I'm able to get an authorization code from the user consentment with this request:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<clientId>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirectURI>&response_mode=query&scope=User.Read.All&state=12345`

I'm able to read users from this another account, but only 1 time, if I try to get users twice, I get this error message:

`OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.`

and if I try to get a token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token`
I get this error message:

`Provided Authorization Code is intended to use against other tenant, thus rejected.`

I only know my own clientId, tenantId and secret, I don't know what is the customer tenantId

How to solve my issue?
thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:
I'm able to obtain the accessToken with "common" instead of my tenantId

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).